# How to remove alert bar notification if input value on submit is not empty?

Tags: reactjs

I have created an Alert component to display an error message on submit if the input value is empty. However, if I enter a username or text and submit again and if it's not empty this message should disappear.

Created a prop `"SetAlert"` with 2 options message and className which I am passing to the default state.

I am able to remove the notice with a timeout.. but this is not a clean way to do it because of the delay.

My App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import Users from "./components/users/Users";
import Search from "./components/users/Search";
import Alert from "./components/layout/Alert";

const GITHUB_API_URI = "https://api.github.com";
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID;
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET;

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
    loading: false,
    alert: null,
  };

  searchUsers = async (text) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const res = await axios.get(
      `${GITHUB_API_URI}/search/users?q=${text}&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}`
    );
    this.setState({ users: res.data.items, loading: false });
  };

  clearUsers = () => {
    this.setState({
      users: [],
      loading: false,
    });
  };

  setAlert = (message, type) => {
    this.setState({
      alert: { message, type },
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { users, loading } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container">
          <Alert alert={this.state.alert} />
          <Search
            onSearchUsers={this.searchUsers}
            onClearUsers={this.clearUsers}
            showClear={users.length > 0 ? true : false}
            setAlert={this.setAlert}
          />
          <Users loading={loading} users={users} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My Search.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    text: "",
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.state.text === "") {
      this.props.setAlert("Please enter something", "light");
    } else {
      this.props.onSearchUsers(this.state.text);
      this.setState({ text: "" });
    }
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { showClear, onClearUsers } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="form">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="text"
            value={this.state.text}
            placeholder="Search Users..."
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Search"
            className={`btn btn-dark btn-block ${
              this.state.text.length === 0 && "btn-disabled"
            }`}
            // disabled={this.state.text.length === 0 && true}
          />
        </form>
        {showClear && (
          <button className="btn btn-light btn-block" onClick={onClearUsers}>
            Clear
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  static propTypes = {
    onSearchUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onClearUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    showClear: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };
}

export default Search;
```

My Alert.js:

```
import React from "react";

const Alert = ({ alert }) => {
  return (
    alert !== null && (
      <div className={`alert alert-${alert.type}`}>
        <i className="fas fa-info-circle" /> {alert.message}
      </div>
    )
  );
};

export default Alert;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// you can change submit function to:
onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (this.state.text === "") {
    this.props.setAlert({ message: "Please enter something", type: "light"});
  } else {
    this.props.setAlert(null);
    this.props.onSearchUsers(this.state.text);
    this.setState({ text: "" });
  }
};

// and change setAlert to:
setAlert = (alert) => {
  this.setState({
    alert
  });
};
```